# XSL distinct values in Xalan Processor

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, distinct-values

I know maybe there are too many questions regarding to that topic but i still couldn't find necessary XPath for my requirement...

I have an xml input like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
   <product vib="SMS53L08TR">
      <template name="PDF_ENLBL_GS_TR_NEWEULBL_FO">
         <attr name="ProductSubFamily">Dishwashers</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CLASS_2010">EEK_EU_2010.A+</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CONS_ANNUAL_2010">290</attr>
         <attr name="WATER_CONS_2010">3300</attr>
         <attr name="PERF_DRY">TROCKNUNGSKLASSE.A</attr>
         <attr name="SETTINGS">12</attr>
         <attr name="NOISE">48</attr>
      </template>
      <template name="pdf.eudatasheet.gs.fo">
         <attr name="ProductSubFamily">Dishwashers</attr>
         <attr name="CODE">SMS53L08TR</attr>
         <attr name="SETTINGS">12</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CLASS_2010">EEK_EU_2010.A+</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CONS_ANNUAL_2010">290</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CONS">1.02</attr>
         <attr name="POWER_OFF_MODE_2010">0.10</attr>
         <attr name="WATER_CONS_2010">3300</attr>
         <attr name="PERF_DRY">TROCKNUNGSKLASSE.A</attr>
         <attr name="REF_PRG">VERGLEICHSPROGRAMM.EC</attr>
         <attr name="REF_PRG_TEMP">50</attr>
         <attr name="CYCLE_TIME">195</attr>
         <attr name="DURATION_LEFT_ON_MODE_2010">0</attr>
         <attr name="NOISE">48</attr>
         <attr name="CONSTR_TYPE">CONSTR_TYPE.Free-standing</attr>
      </template>
   </product>
   <product vib="BM5201EG">
      <template name="PDF_ENLBL_GS_TR_OLDLBL_FO">
         <attr name="ProductSubFamily">Dishwashers</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CLASS">ENERGIEEFFIZIENZKLASSE.A</attr>
         <attr name="PERF_CLEAN">REINIGUNGSKLASSE.A</attr>
         <attr name="WATER_CONS">17.0</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CONS">1.05</attr>
         <attr name="PERF_DRY">TROCKNUNGSKLASSE.A</attr>
         <attr name="SETTINGS">12</attr>
         <attr name="NOISE">57</attr>
      </template>
      <template name="pdf.eudatasheet.gs.fo">
         <attr name="ProductSubFamily">Dishwashers</attr>
         <attr name="CODE">BM5201EG</attr>
         <attr name="SETTINGS">12</attr>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CLASS_2010"/>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CONS_ANNUAL_2010"/>
         <attr name="ENERGY_CONS">1.05</attr>
         <attr name="POWER_OFF_MODE_2010"/>
         <attr name="WATER_CONS_2010"/>
         <attr name="PERF_DRY">TROCKNUNGSKLASSE.A</attr>
         <attr name="REF_PRG">VERGLEICHSPROGRAMM.EC</attr>
         <attr name="REF_PRG_TEMP">50</attr>
         <attr name="CYCLE_TIME">140</attr>
         <attr name="DURATION_LEFT_ON_MODE_2010"/>
         <attr name="NOISE">57</attr>
         <attr name="CONSTR_TYPE">CONSTR_TYPE.Free-standing</attr>
      </template>
   </product>
</Products>
```

On this xml input i will try to get distinct values of templates :

```
  <Template>PDF_ENLBL_GS_TR_NEWEULBL_FO</Template>
  <Template>pdf.eudatasheet.gs.fo</Template>
  <Template>PDF_ENLBL_GS_TR_OLDLBL_FO</Template>
```

What i am trying to do seems correct but still returns all values beside distinct(pdf.eudatasheet.gs.fo seems twice on output)... By the way $output is the variable name holds all xml document inside on it.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$output//product/template/@name[not(@name = preceding:: *)]">
```

What am i doing wrong on this XPath ? By the way as we need to stick on Xalan processor because of the environment that runs this xslt, i couldn't use distinct-values function of XSLT v2.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go one level higher, try this XPath:

```
select="$output//product/template[not(@name = preceding::template/@name)]/@name"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quite and valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

> as we need to stick on Xalan processor because of the environment that
>   runs this xslt, i couldn't use distinct-values function of XSLT v2.0.

If you are using the Xalan processor, you can take advantage of its own `distinct()` extension function - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
extension-element-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Products">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="xalan:distinct(product/template/@name)">
            <Template>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </Template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bwdws6

---

You should most certainly not use a hack like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$output//product/template/@name[not(@name = preceding:: *)]">
```

See why at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html where you can also learn a method that will work with any XSLT 1.0 processor.